# What dimensional units are used in PyQt4?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

When using "setMinimumHeight(...)/setMinimumWidth(...)" what units are the arguments in? I'm not turning up anything online, the book I bought doesn't address it and based on my experiments the units certainly aren't pixels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those parameters are measured in pixels, but there are other things at play here as well that unfortunately are harder to deal with and may be complicating your measurments.

Take a look at the following two images. The resolution of my screen remains at  3840x2160 but the "Scale Factor" that Windows suggests varies between 100% and 250%.

**Scale Factor = 100%**
[image]

**Scale Factor = 250%**
[image]

The ruler has actually changed size which could give you the impression that the size policy of these isn't equivalent to the pixel size. Note the size of each of these widgets starts at the grey, not at the blue. Additionally, even though Qt maintains the size of the widget in pixels independently from Windows' "Scale Factor", the same can't be said for the label in the center which does change in size depending on the scaling.

I don't know exactly how you are taking your measurements, what the GUI is, or what your display setting is, but those all can contribute to the confusion around sizing in Qt.

Comment: Thank you for that terrific answer!